# How to get all values from dictionary in ordered manner

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I am getting a JSON like this :

```
{
    "count": {
        "2018-03-26 07": 4,
        "2018-03-26 08": 21,
        "2018-03-26 09": 34,
        "2018-03-26 10": 43,
        "2018-03-26 11": 64,
        "2018-03-26 12": 48,
        "2018-03-26 13": 31,
        "2018-03-26 14": 45,
        "2018-03-26 15": 48,
        "2018-03-26 16": 45,
        "2018-03-26 17": 40,
        "2018-03-26 18": 44,
        "2018-03-26 19": 58,
        "2018-03-26 20": 49,
        "2018-03-26 21": 60,
        "2018-03-26 22": 46,
        "2018-03-26 23": 35,
        "2018-03-27 00": 34,
        "2018-03-27 01": 36,
        "2018-03-27 02": 16,
        "2018-03-27 03": 23,
        "2018-03-27 04": 14,
        "2018-03-27 05": 12,
        "2018-03-27 06": 12,
        "2018-03-27 07": 1
    }
}
```

Now to get all values from this dict I tried [dict allValues] but it is returning dictionary in unordered format. 
It will take more effort to create these keys manually and get all the values in ordered manner.
What i want is all these value (4,21,34,...) in the same order as they are coming because I have to use these values to draw some kind of graph.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Define the "order" you want. Also, a Dict is not ordered. In other words, show us the result you want and why.

Comment: I edited the question for what order i want @Larme

Comment: As the "key" are coming. I think that your keys are time stamped for the first part and the second part it's in order (or represent the hour).

Comment: Since the JSON is poorly constructed, I would advice to set the date sorting at web api end.

Comment: @Nitish Actually people are using same api's on web from long time. It can't be changed. Btw I got the required answer from Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *jsonStr = @"{\"count\":{\"2018-03-26 07\":4,\"2018-03-26 08\":21,\"2018-03-26 09\":34,\"2018-03-26 10\":43,\"2018-03-26 11\":64,\"2018-03-26 12\":48,\"2018-03-26 13\":31,\"2018-03-26 14\":45,\"2018-03-26 15\":48,\"2018-03-26 16\":45,\"2018-03-26 17\":40,\"2018-03-26 18\":44,\"2018-03-26 19\":58,\"2018-03-26 20\":49,\"2018-03-26 21\":60,\"2018-03-26 22\":46,\"2018-03-26 23\":35,\"2018-03-27 00\":34,\"2018-03-27 01\":36,\"2018-03-27 02\":16,\"2018-03-27 03\":23,\"2018-03-27 04\":14,\"2018-03-27 05\":12,\"2018-03-27 06\":12,\"2018-03-27 07\":1}}";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];

NSDictionary *countDict = jsonDict[@"count"];

NSArray *keys = [countDict allKeys];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH"];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString * _Nonnull dateStr1, NSString * _Nonnull dateStr2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];

NSMutableArray *valuesSorted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *aDateStringKey in sortedKeys)
{
    [valuesSorted addObject:countDict[aDateStringKey]];
}
NSLog(@"valuesSorted: %@", valuesSorted);
```

What's the logic:
Retrieve all the keys.
Sort the keys.
Iterate through that sorted key and append the corresponding value.

In your particular case, the `NSString` dates are comparables easily, and you could write instead :

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Instead of :

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH"];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString * _Nonnull dateStr1, NSString * _Nonnull dateStr2) {
    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr1];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateStr2];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

But that's a particular design because you have they have a `dateFormat` that allows it. Not all `dateFormat` allow it, so I wouldn't recommend to only base your thinking on that.

Answer (score 2):

use dictionary instance method sorted like this:

```
let dict = ["A": 123, "B": 789, "C": 567, "D": 432]
let dictValInc = dict.sorted(by: { $0.value < $1.value })
```

result will be

> [(key: "A", value: 123), (key: "D", value: 432), (key: "C", value: 567), (key: "B", value: 789)]

in objective-c you can sort dictionary keys using there values

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"A": @(123), @"B": @(789), @"C": @(567), @"D": @(432)};
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSString *first = [dict objectForKey:a];
    NSString *second = [dict objectForKey:b];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

and finnaly if you want your array be sorted by their keys:

```
 NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
 NSArray *sortedKeys = [keys sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
     return [a compare:b options:NSNumericSearch];
 }];
```

Comment: please look at the tags it's obj c

Comment: I don't think that your code is what want the user. If you check the author answer the target result is "(4,21,34,...) ", It's not starting with a "1" (which is the last value on its sample).

Comment: yes but if he sort using where values as i mention above, he will get keyes which are sorted with there values. for example: he will get 
"2018-03-27 07"  value  is 1
"2018-03-26 07" value is 4
and so on...

Comment: Actually question was not about sorting, its about getting the same order while fetching all the values. @JabaOdishelashvili

Comment: It seams that you json are ordered by their keys. Am i right? so you can sort your dictionary with their keys. if it's not, than you can't achieve this, because json is unordered set.

Comment: If you take my code and apply yours to `countDict`, you'll see that `sortedKeys` are not the same. While your code is correct, it's not what want the user.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
    ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: your answer is not related to the question, plz update the answer based on answer